# How to 'hide'/'not call' screen keyboard(soft input) on click event for EditText

Tags: android, events, listener

I'm doing my application with my tablet, is there anyway to consume the onClick event?

it's like:

```
cdProduto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(produtos.this, calc.class));
        }
});
```

Comment: Please explain more. Your question's title seems to have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: What wigdet? A Button or what? If a button this is correct.And please fix your title. It has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the OnScreen keyboard you can use:
`this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);`

or in the Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Comment: Try looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215476/hide-virtual-keyboard-in-android